# TFS branching strategy for web site

Tags: tfs, version-control, branching-and-merging

We have a web site that is currently in production (code is in TFS under "production branch") and we also have a set of new features that are being developed in a separate branch called "feature branch". The feature branch was created using the production branch as its parent. Testing for the new features so far has been done by pushing code from the feature branch to a QA server.

Question: What is the best way to manage the branches after our release, assuming we're going to work on another set of features?

Option a: After deployment of the new features to production (which we're planning on doing by pushing code from the feature branch to the production server) we could merge code from the feature branch back down to the production branch and develop the next round of new features in the feature branch again. But there's a risk that the resulting production branch might have issues (bad merge?), so I would be nervous about deploying that to production without spending some time on re-testing the production branch. Also, what if we discover after a while that our feature branch needs to be rolled back? If we had left our old production branch alone we could have simply pushed that branch onto production which would put everything back to a previously working state. That is no longer such an easy option if we merge the release branch into the production branch after release.

Option b: We could consider our existing feature branch to be our new production branch, and create a new branch off of it (say, "feature branch 2") and stop using our previous production branch. This seems like it would work fine, but we'd eventually have a long chain of branches, built on top of each other. That seems like it could at some point get cluttered. Not sure if this is really an issue, beyond having to know where in the chain we currently are.

Does anyone have experience with these different strategies, if so what is your recommendation for which one to pick (or is there a better 3rd option)?

**UPDATE 3/25/2016 ** 
In the end I went with option a. After releasing the feature branch to production I waited a few days to make sure that it was stable, made a few hotfixes to the feature branch and pushed out to production as needed. Then when I was reasonably sure that the release had gone according to plan, I merged from the feature branch to the production branch. I then did sanity checking of the merge to verify that all looked OK. At that point the production branch went back to being the true production branch, and the feature branch was used for the next round of new features.

Comment: The first option results in a codebase in production that's *different* from the one in the "production" branch, which certainly isn't ideal. (If not a flat out lie of the source control system.) The second option sounds like a rabbit hole of branching and re-naming branches that nobody should ever have to do. Why not merge features into the production branch, test them, and deploy from that? (Note: In my opinion you're discovering the problem with having branches in the first place... merges are painful. Have a single path of source changes. Make changes there, test them, deploy them.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Agreed that neither option is utopia. We don't merge into the production branch, then test then deploy because that would leave us with a production branch that is out of sync with what's really in production for some time during testing, before deploying. So if during that period we wanted to quickly fix something in production without the new features we'd be stuck.

Comment: Does your source control system not retain a history of changes?  If you needed to do a hotfix, couldn't you create a temporary branch from a point in time and fix from there?  Then merge that fix back into the ongoing branch afterward?  If your source control system doesn't allow you to revert to a previous moment in time then it sounds like you need a new source control system...

Comment: Yes we use TFS and could create a temporary branch and merge back for the hotfix. I guess I'm not seeing that as an improvement over option b though, since it will necessitate another branch.

Comment: See this article in particular the section "Branch Deploys" https://zachholman.com/posts/deploying-software  Deploy the feature branch, then only when things are stable, merge the feature branch into the production branch, test it, then you can treat the production branch as a true production branch again.

Answer (score 0):

> After deployment of the new features to production (which we're planning on doing by pushing code from the feature branch to the production server) we could merge code from the feature branch back down to the production branch and develop the next round of new features in the feature branch again.

This would mean that what's in *production* doesn't match what's in *the production branch*.  (Or *might* not match, which is just as bad.)  It relies on the merge to be successful without ever actually testing that merge.

> We could consider our existing feature branch to be our new production branch, and create a new branch off of it (say, "feature branch 2") and stop using our previous production branch.

What's the end game there?  By the time you get to "feature branch 137" you might start to question the wisdom of this approach.

---

What you're essentially discovering is that branching and merging is, well, *painful*.  Merging is basically the act of making and testing code changes which don't actually provide any business value.  It's the very definition of cruft.  Unless the company literally sells source control branches, it's unnecessary overhead.

So... Why have all these branches in the first place?  It sounds like the problem being solved is an artificially invented one.  Consider for a moment a strategy *without* permanent branches...

- Have a single main codebase tracked in source control.
- Make and test changes in that codebase.
- When a specific version of that codebase is approved for release, release it.
- Continue making and testing changes in that codebase.
- **If** a hotfix is needed, create a temporary branch from the point in time of the previous release.  Fix in that branch, test and deploy from there, merge back to main and continue working on features.  Delete the temporary branch at your convenience.

You can create temporary branches for all sorts of things.  Prototyping features which take longer than an iteration, a sandbox for technology proof-of-concept changes (such as trying out an entirely new DAL framework), etc.  But everything hangs off of the single "source of truth" codebase.

Having a "Production" branch and a "Development" branch as permanent fixtures side-by-side basically means that you have two sources of truth.  Any time you have multiple sources of truth, you have zero sources of truth.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that we are continuously having to make tweaks to our production web site. These are mainly content changes but also the occasional bug fix. These happen about once a week or so. That's why it's useful to have a production branch that reflects production (without the additional new features) that we can make quick changes to and then release for quick turnaround. Our feature release cycle is very long, the current feature set has been in development for years. If we did what you are suggesting then I guess we'd have a semi-permanent hotfix branch (?)

Comment: @unintentionallyleftblank: That's definitely an issue then. (And honestly, if the majority of effort is in putting out fires and new business-driving features are kept in escrow for large amounts of time then it sounds like someone at the technology management/strategy level is asleep at the wheel.) A long-running feature branch can work, but it's still important to test/deploy from the source of truth rather than assume a merge was good. This business strategy of not deploying features for a *long* time is basically creating overhead. So I guess the company *is* in the business of merging :-/

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions @David. Maybe the way to go is to pick option a. but do careful testing of the merged code from the feature branch to the production branch before deploying that code to production. There will always be some risk in merging code but with testing that risk can be reduced to an acceptable level.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal situation you have a single branch line that you continuously deliver to production by making changes which kick of a release pipeline that leeds to prod. All features and bug fixing hoes through the same process.

In your case there is a lot of maturity that needs to be attained to get there, so you will likely want two branches. One for production (and fixes) and another for new features.

On master/main/trunk you practice continuous release through an automated release pipeline. Have every checkin create a build that is then deployed to a test server. Once approved it automatically pushes to the next environment until you get to prod.

On dev/feature/notprod you practice continuous delivery directly from a build to your development/test environment. Here you add new features and test them. Once you are happy and have stabilised, including pulling bugfixes from master, you merge Back to master and start the release process.

If you are on TFS 2013/2015 you can: http://nkdagility.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

If you are on VSTS you can: http://nkdagility.com/the-high-of-release/

Comment: This seems reasonable, thanks for your response. We don't have continuous delivery by any means at this point  but we will try to get there.

Comment: All you can do is try :) ... and it is worth the effort. Getting that tight feedback loop helps you build the right software and focus your resources on what is needed.